Connecting Azure data factory Integration with On-Premises SSAS Cubes
I've been struggling to find a straightforward solution for connecting Azure data factory  or Fabric to an on-premises SSAS cube. I've searched extensively,
but all I come across are guides on connecting to SQL Server or discussions stating that connecting to SSAS from Fabric isn't currently available. I'm unsure if I'm pursuing the right approach. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated. Would it be sufficient to install a linked server on the machine and utilize SQL Server as the connector?
